# R: Convert dimnames into column in matrix

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe

I was trying to use ["tsne"](https://github.com/jkrijthe/Rtsne) to analyze my data. 
Following the example data ("iris") used in "README" of "tsne",
I tried to structure my own data in a way that it could be used as input for tsne() function.

```
>sampledata

    Gene 1  Gene 2  Gene 3  Gene 4  GeneX
Cell1   Value   Value   Value   Value   Value 
Cell2   Value   Value   Value   Value   Value 
Cell3   Value   Value   Value   Value   Value 
Cell4   Value   Value   Value   Value   Value 
Cell5   Value   Value   Value   Value   Value
```

comparing with "iris", I guess that I need to add an extra column using the dimnames "Cell1" "Cell2" "Cell3"
For dataframe, I guess I could simply do something like:

```
sampledata$sampleids<-rownames(sampledata)
```

But I have no idea how to do similar tricks to matrix. 
Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: I don't know tsne, but a matrix contains values of the same type.  If its values are numbers, you cannot add strings.

Comment: @ user31264, Yes, matrix contains values of the same type. Thank for reminding me about that ( I have just learned that this week, so the fact has yet to take root in my mind...). after rechecking the "README" part, actually `tsne_out <- Rtsne(as.matrix(iris_unique[,1:4])) ` the initial dataframe is coerced into a matrix, and I have already had the matrix, no point to make dataframe first.  Sorry to bother and Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

We can `cbind` but mixing a `numeric` matrix with `character` element results in `character` matrix

```
sampledata <- cbind(sampledata, sampleids=rownames(sampledata))
```

If we just want some identifier, use the row sequence as identifier which will be a numeric

```
sampledata <- cbind(sample(data, sampleids = seq_len(nrow(sampledata)))
```